# Combining 2 rows in table

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have the following data:

```
-------table_a-------
| id | data | value |
| 1  |   5  |   1   |
| 2  |   3  |   3   |
```

My desired output is to merge row 2 with row 1 so that where `id = 1`, data remains to `=5` but the values are added, so `1+3`.

```
-------table_a-------
| id | data | value |
| 1  |   5  |   4   |
```

This is as far as I got with the queries but the first isn't seeming to work. Also this is not for retrieving the data, this is for manipulating the data in the database.

**Current queries (1st not working):**

```
UPDATE table_a SET value = value + (SELECT a.value FROM table_a  a WHERE a.id = 2) WHERE id = 1;
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id = 2;
```

Comment: What is the rule for merging row 2 with row 1?  Does the table have only two rows?  Is the purpose an `update` or is a `select` query sufficient?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The table will have 100,000's of rows. What do you mean by rule? (if you mean what do I want to happen, I want the values to be added, but the id and data of one row to be untouched)

Comment: @GordonLinoff The update is needed as the raw data needs to be changed/updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the logic that you want:

```
UPDATE table_a
    SET value = value + (SELECT a.value FROM table_a  a WHERE a.id = 2)
    WHERE id = 1;
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id = 2;
```

The `update` is not going to work because you cannot reference the table being updated in the rest of the query.  You can use a hack for the update and do:

```
UPDATE table_a
    SET value = value + (SELECT value FROM (SELECT a.value FROM table_a  a WHERE a.id = 2) )
    WHERE id = 1;
```

The double `select` fixes this problem.  The more correct method is to use `join`:

```
UPDATE table_a a CROSS JOIN 
       (SELECT a.value FROM table_a  a WHERE a.id = 2) as a2
    SET a.value = a.value + a2.value
    WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. I didn't know about not being able to reference the update table so thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way on how you can make an accumulative column by joining the table with itself.

I'm assuming the Id column is an identity column,
Hope this helps.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [data] [int] NULL,
    [value] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
           ([id]
           ,[data]
           ,[value])
     VALUES
            (1,5,1),
            (2,3,3),
            (3,4,4)


SELECT  a.id , a.data , a.value + b.value as Sum
FROM    [TestTable] a
    left join [TestTable] b
        on a.id + 1 = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, please check.

```
UPDATE table_a,
(SELECT value as val FROM table_a where id = 2) AS t2
SET table_a.value = table_a.value+t2.val
where table_a.id = 1;

DELETE from table_a where id = 2;
```